# Avoid INDIRECT() in reference to column in Table in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am using **Excel 2010 upwards**.

I am using

```
INDIRECT("Table1[id]")
```

quite often as a reference for column `id` in Table `Table1`, for example in validation rules

```
=COUNTIF(INDIRECT("SCENARIOS[scen_name]");C6) < 2
```

or in

```
=INDIRECT("GENERAL_INFO[bib_key]")
```

But I have read that `INDIRECT()` should be avoided.

OK - how can I avoid the usage of `INDIRECT()` in these cases?

Comment: INDIRECT is used to dynamically build a reference you a cell/range. If you need that capability, you need INDIRECT.

Comment: Forgive me - I am not a frequent Excel user as I try to avoid it - but is this the case for me in the use scenarios?

Comment: No need to ask for forgiveness. Though some people believe they do, nobody really knows everything :-).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you should avoid using INDIRECT whenever there is a sensible alternative.

Excel does not allow structured references to Tables in conditional formats or validation rules. One good solution is to define a Named Range (using Name Manager) that refers to the data portion of the column in the Table, and then use the named range in the conditional format or data validation rule.